# where is “zend_execute” function in php-src?

Tags: php, c

I only see the definition of `zend_execute` function in zend_execute.h, but did not see the implementation.

in zend.c line 1490

```c
    ZEND_API int zend_execute_scripts(int type, zval *retval, int file_count, ...) /* {{{ */
{
    va_list files;
    int i;
    zend_file_handle *file_handle;
    zend_op_array *op_array;

    va_start(files, file_count);
    for (i = 0; i < file_count; i++) {
        file_handle = va_arg(files, zend_file_handle *);
        if (!file_handle) {
            continue;
        }

        op_array = zend_compile_file(file_handle, type);
        if (file_handle->opened_path) {
            zend_hash_add_empty_element(&EG(included_files), file_handle->opened_path);
        }
        zend_destroy_file_handle(file_handle);
        if (op_array) {
            zend_execute(op_array, retval);
            zend_exception_restore();
            zend_try_exception_handler();
            if (EG(exception)) {
                zend_exception_error(EG(exception), E_ERROR);
            }
            destroy_op_array(op_array);
            efree_size(op_array, sizeof(zend_op_array));
        } else if (type==ZEND_REQUIRE) {
            va_end(files);
            return FAILURE;
        }
    }
    va_end(files);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

in zend_execute.h

```
ZEND_API void zend_execute(zend_op_array *op_array, zval *return_value);
```

but i can't find the implementation of this function.

PHP VERSION

```
PHP 7.2.0-dev (cli) (built: Mar 31 2017 10:47:40) ( NTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Anybody Familiar with php-src help me ?

Comment: If my proposed  answer does answer your question, you could consider up-voting it and accepting it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. If my proposed answer does not answer your question for some reason, I would be glad if you provide feedback so that I understand why, and possibly improve the answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Tardis Your answer enough for me to study a few days, failed to accept your answer in time, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that this function is not hard-coded, but rather is generated by a script based on a skeleton, as part of the process of creating the VM.

See:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/README.ZEND_VM#L88

> Executor's code is generated by PHP script **zend_vm_gen.php** it uses
>   zend_vm_def.h and zend_vm_execute.skl as input and **produces**
>   zend_vm_opcodes.h and  **zend_vm_execute.h**. The first file is a list of
>   opcode definitions. It is  included from zend_compile.h. The second
>   one is an **executor code itself. It is included from zend_execute.c**.
>
> zend_vm_gen.php can produce different kind of executors. You can
>   select  different opcode threading model using
>   --with-vm-kind=CALL|SWITCH|GOTO. You can  disable opcode specialization using --without-specializer. You can include or exclude
>   old executor together with specialized one using
>   --without-old-executor. At last you can debug executor using original zend_vm_def.h or generated file zend_vm_execute.h. Debugging with
>   original file requires --with-lines option. By default ZE2 uses the
>   following command to generate executor:
>
> $ php zend_vm_gen.php --with-vm-kind=CALL

The function you are looking for is generated from this skeleton:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_execute.skl#L24

by the zend_vm_gen.php script, there:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_vm_gen.php#L2385

After using the .php script, the generated `zend_execute()` actual code can be found in `zend_vm_execute.h`, which, itself, is included from `zend_execute.c`.

You can actually see a generated `zend_vm_execute.h` which is currently left in the GitHub repository, which is this file generated from that execution, except that the generated file is too big to be viewed normally on GitHub, and you need to view it using GitHub's "raw" view (it is a 2.2 Mb file!), like this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/php/php-src/master/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h

you will see on line 63108:

```
ZEND_API void zend_execute(zend_op_array *op_array, zval *return_value)                                                                                                                                            
{
    zend_execute_data *execute_data;

    if (EG(exception) != NULL) {
        return;
    }

    execute_data = zend_vm_stack_push_call_frame(ZEND_CALL_TOP_CODE | ZEND_CALL_HAS_SYMBOL_TABLE,
        (zend_function*)op_array, 0, zend_get_called_scope(EG(current_execute_data)), zend_get_this_object(EG(current_execute_data)));
    if (EG(current_execute_data)) {
        execute_data->symbol_table = zend_rebuild_symbol_table();
    } else {
        execute_data->symbol_table = &EG(symbol_table);
    }
    EX(prev_execute_data) = EG(current_execute_data);
    i_init_code_execute_data(execute_data, op_array, return_value);
    zend_execute_ex(execute_data);
    zend_vm_stack_free_call_frame(execute_data);
}
```

This [blog post](https://nikic.github.io/2012/07/27/How-to-add-new-syntactic-features-to-PHP.html) by nikic is useful in understanding how to use php-src, through a use case of adding your own new operator.